# What does the effect of "Boost to HC droprate" actually mean?

Tags: android, brave-frontier

In Brave Frontier, what does the effect of "Boost to HC droprate" or "Boost to BC droprate" actually mean?

For example, Archangel's BB (Blessed Sword) is "3 combo Light elemental attack on a single enemy & boost to HC droprate".

Does the boost apply to JUST the hits in the bursts 3 hit's, or does it increase overall HC droprates for a period after the attack (1 turn, 2 turns, the rest of the battle)?  Does it apply to every hit during the period as well?  And do other units benefit from the effect or is it isolated to just the Archangel?

I haven't been able to see a any consistency because of the games natural variance for HC and BC drops and I haven't been able to tell if I'm gimping my team by using Archangel instead of a stronger unit (I don't like straight healers =p).

Any serious theorycrafting out there on how this works?  The official wikia really doesn't shed any light on the topic as far as I can see.

Also, sorry this isn't tagged.  There isn't a bravefrontier tag! XD

Thanks!

Comment: I believe (but I have no hard data to back me up) that the boost is only for the attacks.  Most of the longer-lasting status effects have some sort of icon on the screen to indicate when they are in effect.

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines but I know effects that grant an elemental type to all attacks (like Legionary Melchio's BB (Shining Force)) don't add the status icon to your team.  It just seems like the description in Archangel's burst (and similar bursts) could use a little more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HC have a defualt droprate of 35%, that means each hit has 35% chance of dropping a Heart Crystal.
The boost to HC droprate adds additively to that 35%, so a skill stating "adds 15% to HC droprate" brings the chance of a HC dropping to 50% for each hit.

This applies to all units, newer units' skills state for how long the buffs will last.

Comment: Thank you for this info.  It's been a while since I've personally played but since the post was originally made, they added the status bubbles to show then different boosts were in play.  It's nice to see some straightforward numbers though.

Comment: Yes, the game has come quite a long way, and a lot of it has been datamined, luckily :)

Answer (score 0):

So far in playing this game for a month I've seen numerous units with the same BB or related. I think it works like this:

It increases overall HC droprates for a period after the attack (1 turn, 2 turns, the rest of the battle). It also applies to every hit during the period. Other units do not benefit from the effect because Archangel's BB is an Offense type. Only Support types (like Melchio) can boost other units with their BB. I have no idea how much percentage is added for each boost. But I think it depends on the units level and the BB level of the unit.

Comment: Ya, I've tried testing the numbers a little bit but i can't find any real consistency.  With or without the effect, i get entire turns without hc's.  I bet a larger scale test could divulge some more useful numbers but I've given up on hc drop rate increases as my sole means of healing anyways haha. Thanks for your input!

Comment: Welcome. You may try looking for a helper with Altro or Phoenix. Or maybe try your luck in the rare summon gate. Sad to say I still do not have any of them. T_T